# Vue 2 component renders empty object in some cases

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session-storage

Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong in this code?

```
   if(sessionStorage.getItem('selected')) {
      const fromStorage = await sessionStorage.getItem('selected')
      console.log('From Storage -> ', fromStorage) // logs fine
      this.eventData = JSON.parse(fromStorage)
      const c = JSON.stringify(this.eventData)
      console.log('CLASS ', this.eventData) // logs fine
}
```

This code works some of the time but for some cases the UI renders an empty object despite everything being exactly the same in the console.

I have checked thoroughly the objects coming back from storage and cannot find any differences between them. I have no idea why some are failing to render in the view.

Comment: not your issue, but no need to `await` `sessionStorage.getItem` since `sessionStorage.getItem` does not return a Promise - anyway, the code you show always "logs fine" ... so the issue is that somewhere you expect `this.eventData` to have a value when it does not - i.e. vue is rendering BEFORE this code runs

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the response. Yes, I had a feeling the `await` was not necessary. I just added thinking it might be that the item wasn't back from storage before the page rendered. But it was a long shot. I will look into `this.eventData` more to see what values might be breaking it.